# How to perform web.config transformations/publish for a "passive" web project in Azure?

Tags: azure, publish, azure-web-roles

In my Azure Web Role, I have added an additional web site, much the same as [described here](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/).
The problem is that second web site is referenced by the Site attribute `physicalDirectory` in the `ServiceDefinition.csdef`:

```
<Site name="SecondWeb" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\mySecondWebSite">
```

If I point this attribute to the project location, it will simply package up the whole project folder and publish to the Web Role.
What I want is that the compiled/published profile with my `web.config` transformations is packaged up, much the same as the "default" web project for the Web Role is done.

Is there a way to compile/publish (to a local folder) in the (pre)-Publish event of the Azure Cloud project?